# Fading LED with different frequencies

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, frequency

I have a potentiometer attached to one analog port of arduino (assume A0)
I'm reading the value of that using `input_voltage = analogRead (A0);` which is a value between 0-1023.
So I want to map this value to frequency from 1Hz to 20Hz. Then I want to fade my LED using this frequency.
Tried to doing this map using `int frequency = map (input_voltage, 0, 1023, 1, 20);`
But how can i apply this frequency to LED?
I mean PWM has a constant frequency (about 500Hz). How should I apply frequencies from 1 to 20 to this LED in order to fade it?

Comment: Do you want to blink or flicker instead of dimming the led ? Or does 1Hz mean you want to fade for 1 sec between ON and OFF (20 Hz = 50 ms between On and Off will be no visible difference to immediate switching)

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to change the rate at which you flash an LED? PWM (Pulse width modulation) doesn't to vary the  frequency of the output - it varies the duty cycle (ratio of on-time to off-time) of a fixed frequency output. If you want to dim the output of your LED based on the input pot, it seems to me you should map 0-1023 to 0-255 , an use the 0-255 output to control a PWM output pin. If you want to control the flashing rate of the LED, you need to use something other than PWM.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for your help. What is that "something other than PWM" ? For example timers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library in which you can change the frequency

Here is my example code I did long time ago I had the same problem

Get the library from [here](https://github.com/terryjmyers/PWM)

Go ahead and try example code there and try to understand too.

**Include the library first to code**

my code

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  InitTimersSafe();
}
void loop() {
  //mapping
  long x = map(analogRead(A0),0,1023,1,20);
  bool b = SetPinFrequencySafe(9,x);
  digitalWrite(13,b);
  pwmWrite(9,127);
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print(" Hz ");
  Serial.println(b);
  delay(100);
}
```

Built in led will turn on if the frequency is stetted.

By the way led will turn on in 50% on and 50% off in one cycle in pin 9.

Use only the PWM pins in Arduino 3,9,6 etc.

Now you can change the PWM frequency...

*I just put a led in the female socket in for easiness + terminal in 9 and - terminal in 8 to go to ground that's why I did put pin 8 to low.*

Comment: Thank you for this complete and helpful answer!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to modulate the duty cycle of the PWM for fading a LED? By adapting the frequency between 1Hz and 20Hz, you'll just get changing flashing rates, unless you integrate the PWM output with a (rather large) capacitor.

Comment: @imalipusram I understand but the question asked me to do this using frequency...